# Google app engine- deploy using maven 2.0.0-rc1 is not working

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, appengine-maven-plugin

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Deployment projectId must be defined or configured to read from system state
1. Set <deploy.projectId>my-project-id</deploy.projectId>
2. Set <deploy.projectId>APPENGINE_CONFIG</deploy.projectId> to use <application> from appengine-web.xml
3. Set <deploy.projectId>GCLOUD_CONFIG</deploy.projectId> to use project from gcloud config.
    at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.AppEngineStandardDeployer.setDeploymentProjectAndVersion (AppEngineStandardDeployer.java:152)
```

I tried to provide the projectId using various ways, it is not working. 
I tried to provide the projectId using properties in the pom.xml file

```
<properties>
        <deploy.projectId>APPENGINE_CONFIG</deploy.projectId>
</properties>
```

But that didn't solve the issue. Then I tried to do, mvn appengine:deploy -DprojectId=APPENGINE_CONFIG

also tried -Ddeploy.projectId=APPENGINE_CONFIG. 
I am not sure where I should have this property.

This started happening especially after trying the latest 2.0.0-rc1 appengine-maven-plugin.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin

Answer (score 3):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-rc2</version>
  <configuration>
    <deploy.projectId>something</deploy.projectId>
    <deploy.version>something</deploy.version>
  </configuration>
```

That "something" above could be projectId and version or you can say APPENGINE_CONFIG if you want the projectId and version to be retrieved from the appengine_web.xml. You can also specify GCLOUD_CONFIG. I tried this solution and it worked.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin/issues/338#issuecomment-432742529

Answer (score 0):

(from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin/issues/338#issuecomment-432742529)

You need to set it under the plugin `<configuration>`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-rc2</version>
  <configuration>
    <deploy.projectId>something</deploy.projectId>
  </configuration>
```

However, you can also set it through properties, but in that case, the name should be `<app.deploy.projectId>` instead of `<deploy.projectId>`.

The plugin dev team will work on improving the error message to make this clear.